# laravel migration SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel, schema

When I try to run migration command in laravel i get this error

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

> Before you mark this question as duplicated or vote-down please read
>   the question fully.

The solutions I've found on this site was:

1. Mark as `unsigned` **I have that**
2. Make integer in 2 step **I have that**
3. Schema order issue **I provide screenshot to see that's not the case**

[image: one]

I'm not sure why I get that error, here is my code:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->string('photo');
            $table->text('meta_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_tags')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('publish')->default('0');
            $table->string('comment')->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Any idea?

## Update

Users schema

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: please post the migration file for the `users` table

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din updated

Comment: please try to change the foreign key to `bigInteger` like this: `$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din weird! it's working now :) Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked ^^. I answered it so people can get some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key in `users` table is `BigIncrements` which create an unsigned big integer column, but the foreign key in `posts` table is integer, so they are not the same type.

Changing the foreign key to `bigInteger` will fix it.

so this:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```

instead of:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this code ::

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->string('photo');
            $table->text('meta_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_tags')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('publish')->default('0');
            $table->string('comment')->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
               ->references('id')
               ->on('users')
               ->onDelete('cascade');

});
```